# Order by multiple date columns

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having difficulties approximating a linq query that orders by multiple date columns the way I want it. The problem is that I want to get the first and last row of a table (and set isFirst and isLast variables for these), sorted by two columns; date1 and date2 in such a way that if date1 has a value, this should be used in **ORDER BY**. If  date2 has a value and date1 has none, use date2 in **ORDER BY**.

In T-SQL, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyDataTable 
    ORDER BY 
        CASE
        WHEN date1 IS NOT NULL
            THEN date1
        WHEN date2 IS NOT NULL AND date1 IS NULL
            THEN date2
        END
    DESC
```

And yields this, which is exactly what I want:

```
Id      date1       date2       isFirst   isLast
------------------------------------------------
1234    null        4/3/2014    False     True
1232    3/5/2014    3/7/2014    False     False
1236    8/20/2013   null        False     False
1233    null        4/5/2013    False     False
1235    12/5/2012   null        False     False
1239    9/12/2011   null        False     False
1240    8/5/2011    null        True      False
```

I'm not sure where to go from here,

```
MyDataTable.OrderByDescending(x=>x.date1).ThenByDescending(x=>x.date2)
```

does not give me what I need, since date2 would end up last anyway. 
I tried using a temporary table, setting `date1=date2` where `date1=null`, ordering by `date1` then updating the original table using the `Id`, but this is rather sloppy and I am unsure about the performance cost of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HasValue` and the `?` operator

```
var query  = MyDataTable
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.date1.HasValue ? x.date1.Value : x.date2 ?? DateTime.MinValue);
```

For the first/last part of your question, if you want to fill a collection with this query and it's sufficient to determine it there, you could simply use:

```
var list = query
    .Select(x => new EntityTypeName
    { 
        ..., 
        IsFirst = false, 
        IsLast = false
    }).ToList();

if(list.Count > 0)
    list[0].IsFirst = true;
if(list.Count > 1)
    list[list.Count-1].IsLast = true;
```

Comment: Could `x.date1.HasValue ? x.date1.Value : x.date2 ?? DateTime.MinValue` be simplified to `x.date1 ?? x.date2 ?? DateTime.MinValue`?

Comment: Thanks, this really made my day! I had to alter the statement with an additional condition since I got complaints about the null-coalescing operator when using datetime, but other than that, perfect.

Answer (score 1):

assuming date1 and date2 are nullable:
you can use `?:` operator for simulate if else in EF

```
MyDataTable
    .OrderByDescending(x =>
                        x.date1.HasValue ?
                            x.date1 : x.date2);
```